# is there anyway to release the memory of hardware acceleration,after exit android app.

Tags: android, memory, process, hardware-acceleration

After quit my app a long time,I find "Other dev" still costs a lot of memory,about 16M.

at the same time,There are a lot of "/dev/pvrsrvkm" in /proc/xxx/smaps.

All activitys have destroyed,why "/dev/pvrsrvkm" still use too much memory? how to reduce it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Android you have seen that when we close any application then it does not close completely, It remains in the recent application stack, That you can see by long press the home button(On Most Devices).`Android itself kicked out those recent apps when the other app needs memory`
Or you can do  by `Force close` it.